# Bigcommerce Custom Emails

Tags: email, bigcommerce

When the order status of an order in Bigcommerce is changed, it sends out an email using the template order_status_email.

I want it to send out 2 emails when this happens. (that default email, and another custom email template)

Is there a way to use the API or customize my store to send out an custom email when the order status is changed?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set up your own system to send out the email, but you can access order statuses through the API no problem. Docs can be found here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/order_status

I'd recommend working with the webhooks feature, it'll make this a lot easier. 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks